# Existing div moves when I click to open another div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I load my page, (it's made with Bootstrap - - http://themejulies.tumblr.com) , it looks like this:

[image: image of issue]

When I push the info button in the left corner (which opens a div), the little down arrow towards the bottom of the page moves up.

[image: image of issue]

How do I make it so that I can click the info button to open the div, and the little down arrow does not move up?

And here's the code:

```
    <div class="container-fluid" id="foo" style="z-index:5; display:none; height:auto;">  
       <center>
       <div class="container-fluid" style="height:auto; margin-top:2%;">
       <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-1"></div>
 <div class="col-md-3"   style=" margin-top:1%;"><img class="avatar-style-circle" src="{PortraitURL-128}" /><br/><h3>{AuthorName}</h3></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"  style="background-color:blue; margin-top:2%;"><p style="text-align:justify;">{Description}<br/></p></div></div></div>

   <div class="container-fluid" style="height:auto; margin-top:2%; margin-bottom:2%;">
    <center>
   <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="input-group">

</div>
    <form action="/search" method="get">

      <input type="text" name="q" value="{SearchQuery}" placeholder="{lang:Search}" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
          </form>


    </div><!-- /input-group -->
    <br/>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">   <a href="{BlogURL}ask" button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Ask</a>

    <a href="{BlogURL}archive" button class="btn btn-default" button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Archive</a>

   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Pages
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="z-index:5; margin-left:13%;">
     {block:HasPages}{block:Pages}<li><a href="{URL}">{Label}</a></li> {/block:Pages} {/block:HasPages} 
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 --></center>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="site-wrapper">
    {block:ifShowInfoButton}

   <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');"><i class="fa  fa-info-circle fa-3x" style="position:absolute; margin-left:0.4%; margin-top:0.4%; color:{color:Info Button Color};"></i></a>


     {/block:ifShowInfoButton}



      <div class="site-wrapper-inner">

        <div class="cover-container">






          <div class="inner cover">
            <h1 class="pagetitle" style="position:relative; font-family:{text:Google Web Font name Title}; font-weight:700; color:{color:Title and Tagline Text};">{Title}</h1>
       {block:ifShowTagLine} <p class="pagedesc" style="postition:relative; font-family: {text:Google Web Font name Tagline}, sans-serif; font-weight:500; color:{color:Title and Tagline Text};">{text:Tagline}</p>{/block:ifShowTagLine}
          </div>

          <div class="mastfoot">
            <div class="inner">
            <a name="bottom">  <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-5x"></i></div></a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid" id="bottom">Test</div>
```

Comment: Looks like it stays in the same place, to me.

Comment: As the the great Albert Einstein once stated. "Where is the code? We don't want to click on a link to another webpage."

Comment: @dowomenfart - just added the code, sorry about that.

Comment: @MattEllen -- what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm looking at your images

Answer (score 1):

Set the div that appears when you click the info button to

```
    position:absolute;
    background: #333;
```

this will pull it out of the document flow and will not affect the other divs

or if that is not the effect you were looking for set the div with the down arrow to position: absolute;

Comment: This, along with setting the div with position absolute did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .mastfoot {
   position: absolute;
   }
}
```

the problem is with `position:absolute`